# Use DataGridView to populate text boxes on the form VB .NET 2010

Tags: .net, vb.net, datagridview

I want to display (DataGridView's) selected row contents (each cell value on appropriate text box) on text boxes on the form. This should be fairly simple task for experienced i am sure.

So far i haven't been able to find a single working solution to accomplish that as most of the articles are written for VB / VB 2005/ VB 2008 and not VB 2010.

Any help, tips, answers is greatly appreciated,

Regards,
Ayub

Here is what i have already tried. (I tried putting an image but i can't due to my privileges thanks stack over flow)

```
TextBox1.Text = DoctorsDataGridView.CurrentRow.Cells(0).Value.ToString
```

It strangely works for first 4 selected rows and populate text boxes but fails for the rest of the DataGridView.

WORKING SOLUTION:

```
 txtRoll.Text = grd.CurrentRow.Cells(0).Value.ToString
```

replace 0 - x, to match cell/column.

when about code is put under CellClick event (i.e handles grd.CellClick), it works !

Comment: Please, show us what you already tried.

Comment: please see description again. thx

Comment: Looks like (maybe) any register of the Dataset has a Null value for a field, so DoctorsDataGridView.CurrentRow.Cells(0).Value is null, and then you can't call to the ToString Method. Did you obtain any error message?

Answer (score 1):

You can bind the DoctorsDataGridView's datasource to TextBox1.Text:

```
TextBox1.DataBindings.Add(New Binding("Text", ds, "columnname"))
```

where ds is the datasource, like DataTable, and the BindingContext do the rest for you. Moving the cursor of the datasource by selecting the row int the DoctorsDataGridView changind the data in the TextBox1.